# Why doesn't this code result in a race condition?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, race-condition

Im working on a problem that requires multiple threads to change a shared piece of memory. In order to gain some understanding about how this works in python, I developed the following code to see if I can get a race condition:

```
import threading


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0


def increment(a):
    for _ in range(10):
        a.val += 1


def main():
    a = A()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=increment, args=(a,)) for _ in range(4)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    print(a.val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pretty simple stuff. Each thread should be trying to increment a.val at the same time, which should result in a race condition, since the value is not protected with locks. However, this is not the case. Every time I run this code, the printed value for a.val is 40. Since there are four threads and each one increments a.val 10 times, this is the correct answer. Can anyone explain why this does not result in a race condition?

Comment: The [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) makes sure the `+=` operation is not interrupted by an other thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is the GIL?

Comment: I linked it above.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't think the GIL protects you here. `+=` isn't atomic afaik.

Comment: The `+=` operation is not atomic: https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil

Comment: I guess we have a combination of a rather short workload and the GIL, where the OS does not schedule fast enough to interrupt the thread while doing two operations. But to prove that I would need to replicate the environment.

Answer (score 1):

It does result in a race condition. Your current range is just insufficient to evaluate this. Effectively the first started thread has completed before the next thread can be started.

The specific number that will take long enough that this is no longer the case will depend on your computer resources, for me, modifying the increment function to a larger bound did result in val being a different value on each run.

```py
def increment(a):
    for _ in range(1_000_000):
        a.val += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to `for _ in range(100000)` and got different answers each time.

Otherwise, I guess the computation completes before the next thread is spun up? Indeed, if I add `time.sleep(1)` before `t.start()`, the result is the "correct" one.

==

This is the solution (but not the answer to the question) proposed in the comments:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __iadd__(self, y):
        with self.lock:
            self.val += y
            return self


def increment(a: A):
    for _ in range(100000):
        a += 1
```

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: Ah you are right. Thank you for your response! @Kaus D. why do you think this is, if the += operation is thread safe?

Comment: Thrown in like this is could have any cause.

Comment: The `+=` operation is not atomic: https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil

Comment: If I do 
`with threading.Lock(): a.val += 1`
I still get a race condition.

Comment: The `threading.Lock()` call creates a new lock, a separate one for each thread; what you need here is a shared lock, probably in the object: `with a.lock: a.val += 1`

Comment: Depending on what else you're doing with the object, you could also define an `__iadd__` method on the object, and acquire the lock within it; then your object would have an atomic `+=` and you could just use it.